# Assign std_logic to a std_logic_vector entity port of size 1

Tags: vhdl

If I have an entity that has a dataport `sig_i` specified as follows

```
ENTITY input_sync IS
  GENERIC(
    signal_width : INTEGER := 1;
    synch_depth  : integer := 1
  );
  PORT(
    clk_i : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    rst_i : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    sig_i : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(signal_width - 1 DOWNTO 0);
    sig_o : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(signal_width - 1 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END input_sync;
```

and I specify the generic `signal_width` of this instance as `1` I end up with `sig_i` being

```
sig_i : in std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
```

Is there a possibility to assign a normal `std_logic` to this port or do I always have to go the extra round of introducing an intermediate `std_logic_vector` for the assignment?

```
signal temp : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
signal data : std_logic;

temp(0) <= data;

u1 : input_sync
generic map(
  signal_width := 1
)
port map(
  ...
  sig_i => temp,
  ...
);
```

Comment: As you're asking I suppose that `sig_i(0) => data,` is not an option?

Comment: Exactly, cause that's a datatype mismatch

Comment: No, it's not. `sig_i(0)` is a `std_logic` and `data` too. No mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array ports can be mapped element by element or slice by slice as long as once you start mapping you map all elements contiguously (not necessarily in order though).

```
u1 : input_sync
generic map(
  signal_width := 1
)
port map(
  ...
  sig_i(0) => data,
  ...
);
```